# Can HTML webpage access c# code instead of PERL scripts

Tags: asp.net

I have `HTML` forms, which have embedded `javascript` and `PERL` code. We have to remove all `PERL` references from the `HTML` docs. The `HTML` calls the `PERL` methods, which are located in `.pl` files, through the `OnClick` setmode call etc. All the `PERL` methods will be rewritten in `C#`. To save the `HTML` webforms, is there a way to call the `C#` methods from the `HTML` forms? Or just redoing everything in `ASP.NET` web application is the only answer? Looking for the minimal option for the `C#` conversion effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom ASP.NET webpage, submit the data from your form to this page and use the `Page.Request.Params` to get the parameters from your HTML form (provided you submit it via POST)

```
string mystring=Page.Request.Params["mystring"];
double Amount =Convert.ToDouble(Page.Request.Params["Amount"]);
```

or `Page.Request.QueryString` if you are using GET method to pass your parameters:

```
string mystring=Page.Request.QueryString[0];
double Amount =Convert.ToDouble(Page.Request.QueryString["Amount"]);
```

Comment: Another option is to use Generic Handlers (.ashx) files to accept the post.